# Azure Office 365 Powershell Authentication data

Tags: azure, powershell, authentication

So I can run this script and get the users personal email and phone number

```bsh
Get-MsolUser -MaxResults 20000 | select -Expand StrongAuthenticationUserDetails |select  Email, PhoneNumber |Export-Csv C:\Temp\LicensedUsers9.csv
```

I can get this script to give me the obvious data it requests

```bsh
Get-MSOLUser -MaxResults 200000  |Select-Object  DisplayName, UserPrincipalName, isLicensed, OtherMails, MobilePhone, PhoneNumber, TelephoneNumber | Export-Csv C:\Temp\LicensedUsers32.csv
```

I cannot figure out how to get the first script to include the UPN. If I add it all I get is blanks in the cells

My plan for this is to cross reference data to upload for the Office 365 password reset but I want to merge the data and not overwrite what is there

Answer (score 1):

This worked
Get-MsolUser -EnabledFilter EnabledOnly -All | Select UserPrincipalName, DisplayName, MobilePhone, AlternateEmailAddresses, AlternateMobilePhones -ExpandProperty StrongAuthenticationUserDetails | Export-Csv C:\Temp\LicensedUsers321.csv

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the requirements for those cmdlets, but I see what's needed.

We need to build a custom property, and use an expression to expand the value of the nested property we want.

```
Get-MsolUser -MaxResults 20000 |  
    select @{label="Email";expression={$_.StrongAuthenticationUserDetails.Email}}, 
           @{label="PhoneNumber";expression={$_.StrongAuthenticationUserDetails.PhoneNumber}},
           UserPrincipalName  | Export-Csv C:\Temp\LicensedUsers9.csv
```

What this is doing, is creating custom NoteProperty(s), and adding them to the result of our `select` statement. The reason we need to do this, is because the value of the `StrongAuthenticationUserDetails` property is a nested object, most likely a hashtable (though I can't check to be certain), and we want to expand it inline, while grabbing the other non-custom properties at the same time.